# How to check for the property type of an `unknown` value?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function, which could receive an unknown value:

```
function formatReason(detail: unknown): string {
    if (detail
        && detail instanceof Object
        && detail.constructor.name === 'Object'
        && detail.hasOwnProperty('description')
        && typeof detail['description'] === 'number'
    ) {
        const output = detail['description'];
        return output;
    }

    return '';
}
```

The `detail` parameter could be any value. If it's an object with a `description` property of type string, the function should return that property value, otherwise empty string.

First, do you recommend using `any` or `unknown` for the `detail` parameter?

Second, no matter what I do, the type for `output` ends up to be `any`. How can I make sure it is `string`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe please don't remove useful content from StackOverflow without stating why you're doing it.

Answer (score 27):

**Edit2:** Dmitry Davydov commented about passing `undefined`. Made the code more versatile by adding a `?`. See updated code and playground below. Undefined wont make the code fail anymore.

**Edit:** Neon corrected some code. The typeguard was not sufficient enough. I updated the example to explicitly assert an `unknown` value instead of an implicit `any`.

---

I'd recommend using `unknown` as it is the type-safe variant of `any`, that being said you probably want to use a type guard to assert the unknown value. This has the effect that the `description` property you're looking for is actually being asserted as a `string` and not as an `any`.

The typeguard:

```
interface IDescription {
    description: string;
}
```

```
public hasDescription(obj: unknown): obj is IDescription {
    return (obj as IDescription)?.description !== undefined
        && typeof (obj as IDescription).description === "string";
}
```

Using it in the codebase will result in an if-statement with some benefits.

```
if (this.hasDescription(detail)) {
    // In this if-block the TypeScript compiler actually resolved the unknown type to the type described in the guard.
    console.log(detail.description);
}
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBEIGcFWABzGAHsRkBvAWAChk7kATbXAo0gLmSzDxAHMA3DQC+NGggA2cLFmQBxAK5woDCmNr18CgEYTgCZAAtpmHHkIkQACmLaAVpwUgA1iGIB3EAEpOtu8mBZDGZzNjIqDXp6KAgwBSgyG3tkaTRTFgtSLwB+ADomM1ZLZABCAF4y5CcmGFAIBhoopvoAMhbkMABPfAhiGGQk-1TgwszvfJCi0mQKyoAibl4+OaFI5FFqEXUEUm5kPiUVGeQQCHd5Q4YrL1WaCVjkADc4CUcXN09j8kZJsc45gCMACYAMxzdare5gJ4vIFvVweMiVb5uAoZML-ODaBDgjY0YD9KwHZQMXLGLDpUKWKzPCReLxqNY7EBYYj3XISYh8GkvCajMI3LabagEgbElRkky-MI8iRA+mMqLM1nsznc2lAvnoyyC6h4kWE8Wk8mUqbWaoQWqnBgKiJK3ZsiAcrlWADkfGI0ItVvqrt1GyAA) a playground for you to see how that works (note how only `123` is being outputted to the console).

---

An example implementation for your specific problem:

```
function formatReason(detail: unknown): string {
    if (this.hasDescription(detail) {
        return detail.description;
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: In your type guard, `obj` is implicitly of type `any`. In your playground script, you are passing `unknown` type values to it, but it doesn't matter, because `any` accepts all types including `unknown`. If you declared `obj` as `unknown` in your type guard, it would stop working. I assume, however, that the questioner wanted to know whether you would recommend using `unknown` as type for the type guard argument.

Comment: The code will fail miserably if the we pass "undefined" to hasDescription [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBEIGcFWABzGAHsRkBvAWAChk7kATbXAo0gLmSzDxAHMA3DQC+NGggA2cLFmQBxAK5woDCmNr18CgEYTgCZAAtpmHHkIkQACmLaAVpwUgA1iGIB3EAEpOtu8mBZDGZzNjIqDXp6KAgwBSgyG3tkaTRTFgtSLwA6JjNWS2QAQgBeEuQnJhhQCAYaKIb6ADIm5DAAT3wIYhhkJP9U4PzM71yQgtJkMvKAIm5ePhmhSORRahF1BFJuZD4lFSnkEAh3eX2GKy9lmglY5AA3OAlHFzdPQ-JGcZHOGYBGABMAGYZqtlrcwA8ngCXq4PGRyp83HkMmFfnBtAhQWsaMBelY9soGNljFh0qFLFZHhIvF41CstiAsMRbtkJMQ+FSnmNhmErht1tQ8X1CSoSSZvmEuRIAbT6VFGczWezOdSATzUZZ+dQcdRRcTSeSJtZKhBqscGF4aEA)

Comment: Here is more robust alternative:
`typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && 'property' in obj`

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a great way to write this code until [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) is implemented.  In the meantime, it's up to you whether you prefer `any` or `unknown` (with some casts if you are using `noImplicitAny`, as I'd generally recommend).  I wouldn't worry about the type of the `output` local variable because you've declared the return type of the function as `string` anyway.

Comment: For those not wanting to click the link: `if (typeof x === 'object' && 'a' in x) { /** typed x allows x.a */}`. Available in typescript v4.9.5

Answer (score 2):

This really should be built into typescript!

Anyway here's my slightly more generic variant, that will return the string value of the property if is present.

```
function getStrProp(o: unknown, prop: string): string | unknown {
    try {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        const p = (o as any)[prop]
        if (typeof p === 'string') {
            return p
        }
    } catch {
        // ignore
    }
    return undefined
}
```

My typical use case if for error handling

```
try {
    httpServer = https.createServer(...)...
} catch (err) {
    if (getStrProp(err, 'code') === 'ENOENT') {
        throw 'HTTPS certificates missing: ' + getStrProp(err, 'message')
    }
```