# Typescript check propery for unknow type

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I have an api request and for error statement. I want to return message from payload.

But message object can change depending on error. For example, payload object can be

```
{ message: 'Not Authorized', type: 'service.not_authorized' }
```

or

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR",
            "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
            "detail": "Authorization code is expired.
        }
    ]
}
```

**I can't create interfaces for all possible payloads.**

In JS, basically I can write this :

```
if(payload && payload.message){
   return payload.message
}

if(payload && payload.errors){
  const message = payload.errors.length>0 ? payload.errors[0].detail : 'Error'
  return message;
}
```

Now I can try to do this with Typescript

```
import axios from "axios";

interface IApiError{
    category:string,
    code:string,
    detail:string
}

const CustomError=<T>(e:T):string=>{
  let message="";
  if(axios.isAxiosError(e)){
    const payload = e.response?.data; // payload:unknown

    if(payload){
            if(typeof payload === 'object'){
                if(payload.hasOwnProperty('message')){
                    message=payload.message; 
                    // Error : Property 'message' does not exist on type 'object'.
                }
                else if(payload.hasOwnProperty('errors')){
                    const errorsArray:IApiError[]=payload.errors;
                    message=errorsArray[0].detail;
                    // Error : Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'object'.
                }
            }
        }
   }
 return message;
}
```

How can I solve this?

**Edit**

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624117/how-to-check-for-the-property-type-of-an-unknown-value). But according this we should create interfaces and typeguard for every possible payload option.

Comment: Is `axios` a dependency?  If so, maybe tag the question as such.  If not, please remove references to it in your example code.  Also, what's `T` in your example? Please [edit] the code so that, when pasted into a standalone IDE, it reproduces your issue and only your issue (i.e., please make it a [mre])

Comment: I mean, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjn31w) works for you, but without a [mre] I can't be sure.

Comment: @jcalz I update the code. Actually this method design for different error instances. So I use 'e' as generic variable.

Comment: For this scenario *e* is instance of axios error. And message coming from response data. And returns unknown type.

Comment: e.response -> AxiosResponse  | undefined    **e.response.data -> unknown**

Comment: Since it seems you need axios knowledge to answer this (I have no idea what `AxiosError` is ) I've tagged the question with axios so hopefully someone else can help here.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your responses. Actually you think I have a variable and it's type is unknown. I expect it will be object and according it's properties I return a message.

Comment: @jcalz I guess I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I found a solution. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70031969/6663056) I created a function.

```
// Basically it takes 3 arguments
// o -> Object that we don't know what is look like
// prop -> The name of prop that we are looking for
// type -> A variable with the same type with our prop
// Because I didn't find to send type to method in typescript 
// (for example string,number,boolean)
const getProp = (o: unknown, prop: string, type:any): any => {
   // Checks whether the object contains the requested prop
   const p = (o as any)[prop]
   // If this field instance of requested type
   if (typeof p === typeof type) {
       return p;
   }
   return undefined; 
}
```

Let's test this for different scenarios.

```
let obj:unknown={ message: 'Not Authorized', type: 'service.not_authorized' }

let obj2:unknown={
  "errors": [
      {
          "category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR",
          "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
          "detail": "Authorization code is expired."
      }
  ]
}

// In first object I looking for message field and it should be string
let res=getProp(obj,"message","");
res ? console.log(res) : console.log("Not Found");
// console result -> Not Authorized

// In second object I'm intentionally sending the wrong type
// There is a field with name 'errors' but it's type is array
res=getProp(obj2,"errors","");
res && res.length>0 ? console.log(res) : console.log("Not Found");
// console result -> Not Found

// I send true types
res=getProp(obj2,"errors",[]);
res && res.length>0 ? console.log(res[0].detail) : console.log("Not Found");
// console result -> Authorization code is expired.
```